# Clicking on hidden div elements using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am testing an application where I have to click a menu button, which displays a set of menu settings. I have to click on one of the menu options to navigate a page. The sample HTML code is as follows.

```
<custom-icon icon="menuDown"></custom-icon>
<div class = "settings" hidden="hidden">
<div class="settingItems"> View Settings </div>
</div>
```

Here, If i click on the custom icon(a button), the hidden options div becomes visible and I can click on the View Settings div to navigate to a page. But as the settings div is hidden, I am not able to access it. Could anyone please help me with this. My main motive of flow is to click on the View Settings button (which is in the hidden div) and navigate to another page

I have tried clicking on the custom-icon and clicking on the View Settings div. I am getting an element not clickable error. I'm guessing that clicking on the custom-icon is not making the settings div visible. I also tried making the hidden div visible with this code.

```
WebElement settingsMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='settings']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) browserDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.height='auto';arguments[0].style.visibility-'visible';",settingsMenu);
```

Even this doesnt work

Comment: Did you tried to wait before clicking the element?

Comment: are you able to click 'View Settings' menu manually?

Comment: Also try adding implicit wait after webdriver initialization  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

Comment: @Yosuva A and AndiCover . The implicit wait before clicking the element is working. Thanks guys 

Comment: @SaiKrishna Great. I just added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding implicit wait after webdriver initialization or before clicking the element.
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;`